# Custom list array adapter designed for performance : where to add listeners?

Tags: android, performance, listadapter

I've written a custom listview array adapter, with the recommended pattern that says that we should use a ViewHolder inside getView() method in order to gain performance (and battery ?). Where I am in trouble is where should I add listeners to my checkboxes components. I will be more explicit after my listview adapter source file :

```
package com.loloof64.android.chess_position_manager.file_explorer;

// all my importes (eluded)

public class FilesListArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListFileElement> {

    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<ListFileElement> elements;
    private final ArrayList<ListFileElement> selectedElements = new ArrayList<>();
    private boolean isSelectionMode = false;

    public FilesListArrayAdapter(Context context, ListFileElement[] objects) {
        super(context, R.layout.file_list_view, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.elements = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(objects));
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = convertView;

        // reuse views
        if (rowView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowView = inflater.inflate(file_list_view, parent, false);

            // configure view holder
            FileItemViewHolder viewHolder = new FileItemViewHolder();
            viewHolder.checkBoxView = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.file_list_item_checkbox);
            viewHolder.nameView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.file_list_item_name);
            viewHolder.iconView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.file_list_item_icon);

            // **** 1 *****
            // Should I add item listeners here ?

            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }

        // fill data
        FileItemViewHolder viewHolder = (FileItemViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        ListFileElement bindedElement = elements.get(position);
        viewHolder.nameView.setText(bindedElement.getFileName());

        // **** 2 *****
        // Should I rather add item listeners here ?

        viewHolder.checkBoxView.setVisibility(isSelectionMode ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        viewHolder.checkBoxView.setClickable(ListFileElement.PARENT_DIR != bindedElement);

        if (bindedElement.isDirectory()){
            viewHolder.iconView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_folder);
        }
        else {
            viewHolder.iconView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_file);
        }

        return rowView;
    }

    public boolean isSelectionMode() {
        return isSelectionMode;
    }

    public void toggleSelectionMode(){
        isSelectionMode = !isSelectionMode;
    }

    public ListFileElement[] getSelectedElements(){
        return selectedElements.toArray(new ListFileElement[0]);
    }
}
```

Of course, ListFileElement source code is not needed in order to understand my problem. 
You should have noticed sections **** 1 ***** and **** 2 **** in code comment of my source file.

What makes me into trouble, is the item loading efficiency and programm correctness (no bug) : should I add items checkbox listeners when adding control inside ViewHolder (section 1) or after each item view loading (section 2) ?

Comment: Add it in the 1 place. The code that set listeners will be called only once when inflating.

Comment: Come on, forget about view holders: they give you minimal (not measureable) performance boost, see any axisting adapters made by google: do they use view holder pattern?  NO

Comment: pskink is incorrect; view holders are an important performance improvement. As to "Do Google use them?" - they explicitly _force_ usage of them in the new RecyclerView adapters.

Comment: @AdamS did you do any measurements?  I did and believe me,  the gain is minimal...

Comment: Admittedly, I haven't done any measurements (and I can't seem to find any online, other than the [examples here](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html)). For trivial row layouts (say, a single text view) I imagine that inflating it each time is cheap. For a more complex layout, with nested linear layouts, on a low-end device, I'd still rather inflate it once than take the (admittedly, unmeasured) performance hit each time.

Comment: @AdamS i see that you are mixing up view reusing and view holders,  not inflating the view (using convertView) each time getView is called is called "view reusing" and it is VERY important to use that pattern (quote "i imagine that inflating it each time is cheap")

Comment: Ha, you're right. Sorry about that! And a quick Google on the performance of `findViewById` indicates that it's [perhaps not actually as slow as we've been led to believe](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.ca/2013/11/is-findviewbyid-slow.html).

Comment: @AdamS great link!  their results perfectly match my observations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your listeners once, when creating the rows. However, setting them once you need some way of knowing (inside the listener) *what* was clicked. To do this you'll have to specify the element that the row belongs to when binding the view. Something similar to this should work:

```
// reuse views
if (rowView == null){
    ...
    // **** 1 *****
    viewHolder.checkboxView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Checkbox cb = (Checkbox) v;
             int position = (Integer)v.getTag();
             ListFileElement bindedElement = getItem(position);
             if (cb.isChecked()) {
                 // Do something
             } else {
                 // Do something else
             }
         }
     });
    rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
}

// Bind the view
viewHolder.checkboxView.setTag(position);
```

Since you set the position of the item as the tag on the checkbox when binding the view, the checkbox click listener can simply grab that position out of the checkbox tag and acquire a reference to the item.

Alternatively, you could simply set the item as the tag, rather than a position reference!